# Validate on Server site and validate on client site

Tags: javascript, php, validation

i know that Validate on Server is more secure. But can we validate with javascript ? I have more than 500 line of javascript validate for my project so i dont want to do it again. My question is:
-What should we do if user turns off script (on browser).
-How can i hide my js validate code so user cannot see.

Comment: Thats not possible.

Comment: Validating client side is fine, but you then have to do it all again on the server regardless, as that is the only place you can guarantee that it will be done

Comment: Can you please share some of your code?

Comment: as @RiggsFolly say, client side validation is user friendly and nice to have. However attacker can always avoid your client side validation and send what ever he want on server. So have just client side validation is user friendly but zero hack protection. There is no way you can avoid it. Because even if you hide validation code from attacker he can stop request with something like burpsuite and edit it after execute.

Comment: `if user turns off script (on browser). -How can i hide my js validate code so user cannot see.` load the validation script using javascript

Comment: @JaromandaX If javascript is **disabled**..... How are you going to load your javascript using javascript.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I took the part I quoted to mean he wants to "hide the validation javascript if the browser has javascript disabled" - therefore, if the validation script is loaded using javascript, it's only loaded if javascript is enabled ... to be honest, if javascript is disabled, would the browser even load "external" script in script src="whatever" tags ?

Comment: It would still not be invisible. If it is runnable, it can be viewed and messaed with

Comment: if the browser has javsacript disabled, how can it be runnable?

Comment: but yes, there's no such thing as unviewable javascript in the browser

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple tools that can send HTTP POST/GET requests to your web application (server) without the need of using your website where all the inputs are validated using Javascript.

This means you need to validate and sanitize all your inputs at the server side even better than in the front end.

You could use existing mechanisms to support you:

- PHP's [Filter & Validation mechanisms](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php)
- Database input sanitation [using PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Database input sanitization is *not* a good form of input validation. If the input is invalid, you shouldn't be going anywhere near the code for interacting with the database.

Comment: I agree, but still a mechanism that could support you

Answer (score 0):

You can add java script code in js file and then include that js file in java script funtion for validate . 
This code will not hide your js code from user only the thing is user will not able to view your code on same screen.
Example:
=>  Call Following Function On Click Of Submit And Also include jquery library for "$.getScript" function.

```
 function valdateMe() {
     $.getScript("validate.js", function(){
     });
 }
```